# React Ant design file upload only xls file validation

Tags: reactjs, antd

Im using my react project for **[ant design file upload](https://3x.ant.design/components/upload/)**, i have some conflict on this uploading, i try to validate only uploading **.xls** file , but its not working. i change the **png** to **xls** but not working correctly anyone know how to do that correctly?

**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ymlqwt)**

**code here**

```
function getBase64(img, callback) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result));
  reader.readAsDataURL(img);
}

function beforeUpload(file) {
  const isJpgOrPng = file.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.type === 'image/png';
  if (!isJpgOrPng) {
    message.error('You can only upload JPG/PNG file!');
  }
  const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
  if (!isLt2M) {
    message.error('Image must smaller than 2MB!');
  }
  return isJpgOrPng && isLt2M;
}

class Avatar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
  };

  handleChange = info => {
    if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      // Get this url from response in real world.
      getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, imageUrl =>
        this.setState({
          imageUrl,
          loading: false,
        }),
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    const uploadButton = (
      <div>
        <Icon type={this.state.loading ? 'loading' : 'plus'} />
        <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
      </div>
    );
    const { imageUrl } = this.state;
    return (
      <Upload
        name="avatar"
        listType="picture-card"
        className="avatar-uploader"
        showUploadList={false}
        action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
        beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        {imageUrl ? <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" style={{ width: '100%' }} /> : uploadButton}
      </Upload>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to adapt the mimeType of your desired file format (`file.type`) according to the [MIME types docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

For `.xls` you can find the correct type:

> .xls  Microsoft Excel     application/vnd.ms-excel

This will result in the following check:

```
const isXls = file.type === 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
```

Additional you can add a filter to the `Upload` Dialog to show only files with the type you want (see [Antd's Upload Api doc](https://3x.ant.design/components/upload/#API)).

> accept    File types that can be accepted. See input accept Attribute

```
<Upload
        accept="application/vnd.ms-excel"
...
/>
```

Here is a working [Demo Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ymlqwt-ekmjqc).